# Inexpensive ways to cool the house as a renter

Tags: cooling

I am renting a house with a few other people. The house is fairly old and the leasing company refuses to do any expensive renovation and it would be inconvenient to everybody living in the house anyways. My room has a connection to the attic, and unfortunately there is no attic fan in the attic so there is hot air that pushes downward. The living room also has high ceilings. We've already applied curtains to the windows, but are there any particular ways we can cool down the house that isn't particularly expensive?

Comment: It sounds like the house may not have air conditioning. Have you looked in to a window air conditioning unit?

Comment: Modern window units are amazingly cheap, efficient, easy to install, run on 120 V.

Comment: how cheap are we talking here? I was thinking somewhere along the lines of <100 since its a rental. Also, I'm not 100% sure the windows open in the house. They seem to be the non-opening type.

Comment: @Carl Carlson If the windows do not open, I'm surprised it is allowed to be rented since means of egress are typically required in legal bedrooms to escape in case of a fire. That would be the place to start: Try opening the windows if the home is poorly insulated and just trapping radiation from the roof inside the home. That said, some window air conditioning units can be had for about $100, though they may not be large enough to cool a living room with cathedral ceilings. Window air conditioners are portable though so you could spend more on a larger unit and take it with you if you move.

Comment: A $100 air conditioner is a waste of your money, it won't be a durable unit.

Comment: @Harper: I have a $100 box store GE unit on it's 4th midwestern summer,  what do you want for $100?

Comment: @dandavis Oh. Well assuming it's not counterfeit, GE sells fairly good stuff. I guess I'm wrong about the cost of window A/C.